# Margin bottom is being overridden when I need it to be set to a newer value

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following 2 styles:

```
.no-bottom-margin{margin-bottom:0;}
.tab-content{border:1px solid #000;margin-bottom:1em;}
```

On my page I did the following:

```
<div class="tab-content no-bottom-margin">
     Some data here..
</div>

<div class="tab-content">
   Some data here..
</div>
```

The bottom margin is not removed from the first div, I can't understand why?  When I have a look at Fire Bug then then margin-bottom:0; is overwritten.  I need the margin to be set to 0.  How do I do this?

This sample looks stupid, but I have logic on my view that adds the style `tab-content` to the `div`, but if it is the only div on the view then I don't want the margin there, then my design doesn't look consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try making your first CSS delcaration:

```
.tab-content.no-bottom-margin {
  margin-bottom: 0;
 }
```

Combining the classes will increase it's specificity.

Also, you can **re-order the rules so .no-bottom-margin is second** - in CSS, the last rule wins.

Comment: Actually, after thinking about it, my last sentence is the crux of the matter - both selectors have the same specificity. But because .tab-content comes second, that's why its margin declaration wins. I would simply move .no-bottom-margin towards the end of your style sheet, if you are using it elsewhere.

Comment: I mis-used the word "classes" in my answer - I will correct that.

Comment: Now you're editing anyway, you still misspelled bottom. And the OP said no-bottom-margin, not no-margin-bottom.

Comment: hey, it's early, and i haven't had my coffee yet. cut me some slack.

Answer (score 0):

```
.no-bottom-margin {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: What does this do?  Care to elaborate a bit more in your answer?  I use this no-bottom-margin in other elements as well.

Comment: I'm just not a fan of introducing !important unless you need to override styles you didn't create. It negates specificity.

Comment: @chipcullen Yes. Using a style attribute in the div's start tag would be better. Or of course, your answer.

Comment: @BrendanVogt it will overright the style applied on the block elements wherever you use no-bottom-margin margin-bottom:0 will be applied